# MySQL filter out an array of invalid ids

Tags: mysql

I want to send an array of user id numbers to my server and check to see if the user is valid in the database, an example of this would be like so:

```
var user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

It will then check the database and verify that `table.user_id` contains a value for each id. In this example, lets say the table data is as follows:

```
TABLE USERS
-user_id-    -name-
    1        Chris
    2        Tyler
    5        Robert
```

This query would take the array `user_ids` and reutrn the values `3 & 4` as they are invalid accounts.

Comment: Depending on number of valid and invalid ids, it might be useful to select valid from DB, and then filter on client side

Comment: Few obvious options are considering doing the set difference operation at server level with the output of this query `select id from users where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and name is not null`. Writing a stored procedure will be good idea too. Also going for temp table will help to some extent again.